# Multiple Toggle Buttons with their own on/off state icon

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a couple of ToggleButtons inside a HorizontalScrollView, I want each of these ToggleButtons to have a different on and off drawable

ToggleButton:

```
<ToggleButton
  android:id="@+id/toggle_[nameOfToggle]"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
  android:paddingLeft="5dp"
  android:paddingRight="5dp" />
```

I have a selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- currently pressed turning the toggle on -->
<item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_state_on"/>

<!-- currently pressed turning the toggle off-->
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_state_off"/>

<!-- not pressed default checked state -->
<item android:state_checked="true" />

<!-- Default non-pressed non-checked -->
<item />

</selector>
```

*toggle_state_on.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_on_[nameOfToggle]"/>

</layer-list>
```

What is the best way to programmatically achieve this, is there a way to check what toggle button it is and change the drawables of the on/off state based on that?

Comment: is it possible for you to do a list with a adapter instead ?

Comment: do you mean you want to set different selector drawable for each `ToggleButton`?

Comment: @Trucket If I have to, yes. But maybe there is a better way of creating a reusable piece of code

Comment: @JCDecary What do you mean?